# Hibernate: saving an entity with foreign primary key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a database with two entities (*Product* and *Feedback*). Feedback has a single foreign key that refers to Product, whose primary key is an integer. They are therefore in a **one-to-one relationship**.

I want to add a new *Feedback* entry to the database with my web application.
To do so I'm trying to perform a **PUT request** to my Spring server from my Angular client application.

The client has an Object of class `Feedback` with the following attributes (content of `Feedback.ts`)

```
export class Feedback {
  constructor(
    public productId: number,
    public score: number,
    public preferred: boolean,
    public textNote: string
  ) {
  }
}
```

The class `Feedback.java`, server side:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "feedback")
public class Feedback implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "product", unique = true)
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Product product;

    @Column(name = "score")
    private double score;

    @Column(name = "preferred")
    private boolean preferred;

    @Column(name = "textnote")
    private String textNote;

    // ... getters, setters, constructor

}
```

As you can see there is a non-matching attribute: `productId` is a `number`, while `product` is of class `Product`. How can I give the Spring application the correct object in order to `save` it in the database?

I'm trying to follow the Hibernate guidelines and as far as I understood it would be a bad practice to use an attribute in the java class of type `int` instead of `Product`. What should I do?

Comment: Why `product` field in Java class has `@Id` annotation? Do you really want to use `Product` instance as ID for `Feedback`?

Comment: The entity `Feedback` has only one key: the foreign key that references to the product. The point is I want to store in `Feedback` some information that refers one-to-one to the product. I may simply expand the attributes of the `Product` entity, but as the information in Feedback is really rare I don't want hundreds of empty cells in my database. :) I hope given those considerations you will agree that I put `@Id` in the correct place (unless I'm missing some point on Hibernate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new Product with the productId from the FE. Now you can create a new Feedback object with all types set. This you can then store in the database.

[Edit]

Usually, you have data transfer object (DTO)in the backend. Those will as the name suggests transport data do nothing else. Endpoints in the backend will always get DTOs which are the same as in the FE. In your case create a FeedbackDto.

```
public class FeedbackDto {
   Long productId;
   Double score;
   Boolean preferred;
   String textNote;
}
```

The Endpoint will receive this Object which has the same fields as the Feedback from the FE. Spring will create and fill you the object from the values in the JSON body of the request

From the FeedbackDto you create now a Feedback entity:

```
new Feedback(new Product(feedbackDto.productId), feedbackDto.score, feedbackDto.preferred, feedbackDto.textNote)
```

Now you can save this Feedback entity into your database.

Comment: So I should define also a class `Product` in typescript and use it as the data type of the `product` attribute in `Feedback` class? In BE Spring will automatically understand what to do if I do so?

Comment: No not really I would let the front end part be as it is and change the backend a bit. I will edit my answer

Comment: Thank you, I just did as you suggested but when I do the `save()` and subsequent `flush()` I get nothing in the database :( . I tried to print what's inside the `feedback` and `feedbackDto` objects and I get what I was expecting, but when I run `save()` I get the following from Hibernate: Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        feedback
        (preferred, score, textnote, product) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: I asked another question referring to this problem in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60227870/hibernate-not-correctly-saving-an-object-in-the-db

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue as you had, and this blog post helped me solve it: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships. This works very well if you are also using the Spring Data REST, but I think you can adapt it to your usage.

Basically, after you create your `Feedback` entry (with an initial `POST` request), you should perform another `PUT` request to associate the `Feedback` entry to your `Product`. For your example, you could have something like:

```sh
curl -i -X PUT 
 -d "http://localhost:8080/feedback/1" 
 -H "Content-Type:text/uri-list" http://localhost:8080/product/1/feedbackProduct
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend a DefaultConversionService and implement a custom converter to convert id to product

```
 @Configuration
 public static class Config {
   @Bean
   public ConversionService conversionService () {
      DefaultConversionService service = new DefaultConversionService();
      service.addConverter(new IdToProductConverter());
      return service;
   }
 }
```

Then the IdToProductConverter will receive the id and can lookup the product from the DB

```
class IdToProductConverter implements Converter<String, Product> {
    @Override
    public Product convert(String source) {
    }
}
```