# Hibernate not correctly saving an Object in the db (?, ?, ?, ?)

Tags: hibernate, sqlite, persistence

Following from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60225542/hibernate-saving-an-entity-with-foreign-primary-key) question. (I'm using Hibernate 4.)

As suggested in one of the answers I tried using the FeedbackDto-Feedback approach.

Inside my `RequestsController.java` I have this:

```
@PostMapping("/feedback")
public void postFeedback(@RequestBody FeedbackDto feedbackDto) {
    Feedback feedback = new Feedback(new Product(feedbackDto.getProductId()), feedbackDto.getScore(), feedbackDto.isPreferred(), feedbackDto.getTextNote());
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.save(feedback);
    session.flush();
    session.close();
}
```

If I try to print the content of `feedback` and `feedbackDto` I get what I was expecting, but running `save()` and `flush()` I get no data inserted in the database. Why?

Output from hibernate:

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        feedback
        (preferred, score, textnote, product) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Here's the create statement I used to create the feedback table:

```
CREATE TABLE feedback(
  product INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  score NUMERIC,
  preferred INTEGER,
  textnote VARCHAR(255),
  FOREIGN KEY(product) REFERENCES product(id)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the call of the product constructor:

```
new Product(feedbackDto.getProductId())
```

You should first fecth the product object from the database (or create it if doesn't exists and the product's id is enough to create it).

Another problem is in your database representation. You should use an integer ID for your feedback table primary key and have another field to record the foreign key. It is a better approach than mixing ID and foreign key.

So this should be something like this :

```
CREATE TABLE feedback(
  feedbackid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  score NUMERIC,
  preferred INTEGER,
  textnote VARCHAR(255),
  productid INTEGER
  FOREIGN KEY(productid) REFERENCES product(id)
)
```

And then your method should be like this :

```
@PostMapping("/feedback")
public void postFeedback(@RequestBody FeedbackDto feedbackDto) {
    // I assume you have a field productDao in your class
    Product product = productDao.findById(feedbackDto.getProductId());
    if (product != null) {
        // Assuming the product should exists
        Feedback feedback = new Feedback(feedbackDto.getProductId()), feedbackDto.getScore(), feedbackDto.isPreferred(), feedbackDto.getTextNote(), product);
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.save(feedback);
        session.flush();
        session.close();
     } else {
        // return an error code
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I still don't understand why feedback should have a separate id :( Can you please explain better how is that a problem? I explained here why I chose that approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60225542/hibernate-saving-an-entity-with-foreign-primary-key#comment106528191_60225542

Comment: Instead of using DAO I used the following: `Product product =  (Product) session.get(Product.class, feedbackDto.getProductId());`. I therefore obtained correctly the relative product (printing the content works). Passing the object `product` while creating `feedback` as you suggested doesn't solve the issue. :( Still the same behavior

Comment: After adding `implements Serializable` to `Product` it worked :) thanks for your answer. I'll accept it even if it didn't solve completely my problem!